# electromagnetic waves dependence on frame

Tags: electromagnetism

accelerated charge particles emit Electromagnetic waves. So if we take a charge at rest with respect to us that should not emit Electromagnetic radiation, but the same charge observed from the outer space is accelerated so for a observer in outer space it should emit EM waves? How is this possible that for one frame there exist EM wave for another it does not?

Answer (score 0):

In the frame of the particle you just see a constant electric field. From outside this field must change as the particle moves by. Just have a look at [this](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~teviet/Waves/empulse.html).